# Continuity of exponential function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Is the exponential function continuous in $\mathbb{R}^n$? How can one show this? Let's say for a function like $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x, y)=x^y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain is not the entire $\Bbb R^2$, as we have trouble with negative values of $x$. If $x>0$, we have that $x^y=e^{y\log x}$, which is continuous because the one-variable exponential and $(x,y)\mapsto y\log x$ are continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still having lots of trouble with multidimensional continuity. How do I see that $(x,y) \mapsto y \log x$?

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto y\log x$ is continuous because it is the product of the continuous functions $(x,y)\mapsto y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto \log x$. Almost never you'll have to check continuity with epsilons and deltas. Abuse these properties and your previous knowledge of single-variable calculus.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.

First of all, where can we define exponentiation with real arguments and real result?

- If $y$ is a non-negative integer, we define $x^y:=\prod_{k=1}^yx$ (which is the most original definition of exponentiation). In particular $x^0=1$ for all $x$
- If $y$ is a negative integer and $x\ne 0$, we define $x^y:=\frac1{x^{-y}}$
- If $x>0$, we define $x^y:=\exp(y\ln x)$.

Note that this is well-defined, i.e., whenever two of the definitions apply, they give us the same result. Thus the maximal domain of $f$ is
$$ D=(0,\infty)\times \Bbb R\quad \cup\quad(-\infty,0)\times \Bbb Z\quad\cup\quad \{0\}\times \Bbb N_0.$$

As the logarithm, multiplication, and the exponential function are continuous on their domain, we conclude that $f$ is continuous on the right half plane $(0,\infty)\times \Bbb R$.

Because multiplication is continuous, $f$ is also continuous along any line $y=\text{const}\in\Bbb Z$, so we can say that $f$ is continuous at tall points $(x,y)$ with $x<0$ and $y\in\Bbb Z$.

A quick computation shows that for any sequence $x_n\to 0^+$ and $y_n\to y\in\Bbb N$, we have $\exp(y_n\ln x_n)\to 0$, i.e., $f$ is also continuous at the points $(0,y)$ with $y\in \Bbb N$.

Only for $x=y=0$, continuity does not hold, i.e., $x_n\to 0^+$ and $y_n\to 0$ does not imply $x_n^{y_n}\to 0^0=1$. This is precisely the reason why we call $0^0$ an indeterminate (not undefined!) form.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I wasn't able to follow you on your last point. Why does $x_n\to 0^+$ and $y_n\to 0$ not imply $x_n^{y_n}\to 0^0=1$?